# Setting the initial view controller in a page based navigation to something other than the first view

Tags: navigation, watchkit, wkinterfacecontroller

In watchOS, I'm implementing a [Page-based navigation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/app-architecture/navigation/). The page based navigation contains three interface controllers; however, the first interface controller is the one that shows up first. In my scenario, however, I want the second interface controller to load up first and then they can swipe back/forward to see the other controllers. Is there anyway to implement this functionality?

**Approaches tried so far:**

**Attempt:** Connect the interface controllers together using a `next page` relationship segue and set the `Initial interface controller` to the second page.

**Result:** The second interface controller indeed shows up first; however, the first interface controller is completely ignored and you can't scroll back to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to insert in your second controller a call to `becomeCurrentPage()` in the `awake` method:

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    // ...

    becomeCurrentPage()
}
```